# Product Rule Notation Meaning

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S_1,...,S_t$ be finite sets and let $S=S_1 \times ... \times S_t$. The product rule states that $$|S|= _{i=1}^t S_i$$

There is supposed to be some big pi symbol in between the limits which i don't know how to write on latex. But what does this symbol mean in terms of this rule?

Comment: Write "\prod". The symbol $\prod$ works like $\sum$, but the terms are multiplied instead of added. The empty $\prod$ is defined to be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "big pi symbol in between the limits which i don't know how to write on latex" is the product symbol. That is, \begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i=a_1 \cdot a_2  \cdots a_n
\end{equation}
In particular, you are saying that the cardinality of $S$ is equal to the product of the cardinalities of the $S_i$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the accepted notation for the product of the values $|S_i|$ as $i$ ranges from $1$ to $t$.

Just to be clear,  $|S_i|$ is the notation for the number of elements in the finite set $S_i$, also known as the cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

For a set S, |S| denotes its cardinality i.e the no of the elements in S, here the no of elements in S is the product of all the ways you can choose a element from $S_i$ ,like say if the set S is = {1,2,3,4} then no of 3 letter words that can be made with repetition with each letter selected from S is 4*4*4 .